# Hibernate JPA Template fetch

Tags: mysql, hibernate

Hibernate JPA Template fetches list of objects from database. 
Can this be type casted to another class object list??

```
List<Class1> list1 = (List<Class1>) getJpaTemplate().findByNamedQuery("..someQuery..");
```

This is the code which i use now. Class1 relates to a table1 in database. Will I be able to fetch the records in table1 into another `list<Class2> list2;` which has all parameters as table1 and some extra parameters. If I will be able to fetch then will I be able to assign values to those extra parameters through namedQuery ??

Any help appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. But before you have some more concrete questions, go read the following:
[Hibernate inheritance](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/inheritance.html)
and [JPA-QL reference](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/entitymanager/reference/en/html/queryhql.html), point 7.7, where they explain `cat.class`